# Replace ClientCredentials with token Bearer header in OperationContextScope SOAP

Tags: soap, .net-core, header, bearer-token

I am trying to replace **client credentials** with a header, `Bearer Token`, in a **SOAP** service. 
I used WCF web service reference provider and dotnet core in vs 2019. 
*With REST and HttpWebRequest Headers.Add its all fine.*
Im not expirienced in C# and its not that I am looking for a free solution but at this time I accept all help that I can get so please comment..

```
/*
   * client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Creds.UserName;
   * client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Creds.Password;
   */

  using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
  {
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    /*
     * httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
     */

    //String auth = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    //httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth);
    //httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Bearer " + auth);
    //httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    //httpRequestProperty.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    //httpRequestProperty.Headers["Bearer"] = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";


    MessageHeader usernameTokenHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Bearer", "https://api.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/taxering/v1.7", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(usernameTokenHeader);

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
```

The response is as follows

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="auth"'.'
```

Comment: I think you can use the line `httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth);` to add the correct header. Please note that the header type is Authorization and auth is the token: `Bearer<space>token`. The token may have been provided or you have to request it at some provider.

Comment: Hi @RuardvanElburg The token is already provided  (xxxx...), I commented out the syntax I have already tried without success. The MessageHeader beneath could be a solution for soap request but this failed too. The service does not accept the request auth so Im not sure how to claim it..

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/operationcontextscope) documentation I should be able to use MessageHeader when requesting a soap service. Maybee because its .net core(?)

Comment: Ms docs does not have OperationContextScope available for .net core. But I can use OperationContextScope with ClientCredentials.

Comment: **Progress** @RuardvanElburg I had missed to change a link in the service reference (never trust "Change all"). Now that Im running the syntax you proposed I get a new error `Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Validation error` So I have no clue... again :)